# How do I relocate a generator inlet box?

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, receptacle, generator, power-backup

[image: power_inlet]

[image: transfer_switch]

From the images above, I have a 30 amp generator inlet that connects to a transfer switch. I’d like to relocate that inlet box to the outside of the house so that I don’t have to run my L14-30 cable from the generator through an open door or cracked window. I’d like to just plug my generator outdoor safely. I don’t know if I need a different inlet box that’s weather proof and/or different cable to withstand outdoor weather when not in use. This is Florida weather so no harsh winter months but lots of rain and heat in the summer.

What do I need to purchase to make the move? Or can I use the existing inlet box outdoor and just drill a hole for the cable/wire to pass through my exterior wall and then seal it after hooking it up to the inlet box once I place it outdoor?

The inlet box, when placed outdoors, would be right on the opposite side of the wall it’s currently on in the same spot. So it’s a matter of passing its wire through the wall and moving the inlet box right outside of where it currently sits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have what you need. That box or every one I have ever seen are listed for outdoor use. I would open your transfer switch, find a handy spot and drill a hole through the wall install a bushing or short piece of conduit to connect the transfer switch to the inlet and secure the inlet box. I will use caulking around the bushing or nipple to seal it up.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I’ll take this approach. I’ve seen videos on YouTube of people using these outdoors but it was never clarified if it was rated for outdoor use. Glad to see they are

Answer (score 1):

You would need a weather tight box, and a cover that would allow your cord cap (plug) to be connected WHILE it is raining, so usually with a built-in double lipped rubber seal arrangement where the cord cap and inlet cover are matched. Your cord itself would need to be what's called "portable cord", usually type SJOW, and the connection to the cord cap would need to be weather tight with a sealing grommet. You can find these sort of devices at industrial electrical supply houses or places that provide equipment for RVs and trailers. They are NOT inexpensive.
Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: It looks like that his existing inlet box already has such a cover...all the inlet boxes I've researched are weatherproof, at least

Comment: Because sealed outlets are quite expensive, you can simply put a weatherproof "in-use cover" on top of a standard outlet to shield it from rain while in use. Those are inexpensive (less than $10) and will accept pretty much any type of outlet.

Comment: Here is an example of such a product: https://www.homedepot.com/p/TAYMAC-1-Gang-Horizontal-or-Vertical-Weatherproof-Extra-Duty-In-Use-Cover-Gray-MM420GB/204208078

Comment: Those photos are not listed inlet boxes and would not meet code. The OP has an inlet box.

Comment: Thanks for all of the responses. It’s been helpful